# Angular 4 : Why compiling a project with my package hosted with npm trigger a 'makeDecorator' error on compilation

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I got this error since I started to code my two npm packages, and I can't find a solution for this issue. Each time I run ng serve, I have this error, and then if I just add a space character and Ctrl+S a file (to run an Angular-CLI compilation) It diseapper ! How to resolve this ?

Error :

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling
>   function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider
>   replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported
>   function, resolving symbol NgModule in
>   D:/GitHub/angular-npm/ngx-heyl-modal/demo/node_modules/ngx-heyl-snackbar/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module.d.ts, resolving symbol NgModule in
>   D:/GitHub/angular-npm/ngx-heyl-modal/demo/node_modules/ngx-heyl-snackbar/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol NgModule in
>   D:/GitHub/angular-npm/ngx-heyl-modal/demo/node_modules/ngx-heyl-snackbar/node_modules/@angular/core/src/core.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol NgModule in
>   D:/GitHub/angular-npm/ngx-heyl-modal/demo/node_modules/ngx-heyl-snackbar/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol SnackbarModule in
>   D:/GitHub/angular-npm/ngx-heyl-modal/demo/node_modules/ngx-heyl-snackbar/index.ts,
>   resolving symbol SnackbarModule in
>   D:/GitHub/angular-npm/ngx-heyl-modal/demo/node_modules/ngx-heyl-snackbar/index.ts

my packages : (With all my sources on Git)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-heyl-modal

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-heyl-snackbar

**EDIT :**

I tried to use npm link with a simple project : empty service, empty component (just a div in the html file, no input no functions at all) and this issue is still here. I think it's because of the NgModule, maybe I'm wrong in how I wrote it ? or my package.json ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not ship `node_modules` folder in your package.

You must keep in mind that you’re writing library for Angular project. Since project itself must have Angular core as a dependency the library should not include Angular sources in the bundles it produces. To do so you need to setup peer dependencies in package.json file.

```
{
  ...  
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0"
  }
  ...
}
```

Simple way to create AOT compatible angular library is just to run `ngc` but i would advice you to follow [Angular 4 package format](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/edit)

Here is my test library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zuz/lib ([source](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-package-format-library), peerDependencies in  [package.json](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-package-format-library/blob/master/src/lib/package.json#L18-L21))

See also these links for possible solutions

- https://medium.com/@trekhleb/how-to-create-aot-jit-compatible-angular-4-library-with-external-scss-html-templates-9da6e68dac6e
- https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular-libraries-are-fun-fece73cceb05
- https://medium.com/@tinesoft/easily-create-and-publish-your-next-angular-library-with-yeoman-via-generator-ngx-library-88feb0aa63fc

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just removed all my dependencies and added the "peerDepedencies" and the error vanished ! I'll read later all the links you added to your answer, I'm sure they will be usefull !

Comment: I just have a small question, is there a way to tell my IDE (IntelliJ here) that @angular/core is correct and to not underline it in red ? (and to have auto-completion)

Comment: You can have different package.json files. One for develop and one for npm

Comment: How to do that in the same folder ? I don't understand how to use different package.json..

Comment: You can build your library into destination folder and there have package.json for npm